# sh: svelte-kit: command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte

I'm following the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs) on starting a SvelteKit project.

When I run this:

```
npm init svelte@next my-app
cd my-app
npm install
```

Everything looks great. Then I execute this command:
`npm run dev`

And I get `sh: svelte-kit: command not found`

I'm running node `v16.13.1` and npm `8.1.2` -- I updated node yesterday and I'm wondering if that's the cause of my problems, since beforehand I had no problem running a SvelteKit project.

Comment: Can you check if your node_modules folder definitely has all dependencies downloaded when you ran `npm install`. If node_modules folder didn't created at all, check the permissions (probably try stat or chmod commands) of the directory and fix it. If you have `node_modules` created but didn't install all dependencies, just to be sure check if NODE_ENV is not set to `production`, if it is npm will not install devDependencies which would mean you might not have the libraries that you want to run. Hope that helps

Comment: Make sure you have a later version of node. I got this error on v14 and upgraded to v16 and it worked

Answer (score 4):

Did you actually run `npm install`?

Comment: So weird. This happened to me all of a sudden while working on a project. Running `npm install` fixed it.

Comment: Even after running npm install, it is not working for me. Event tried deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and .svelte-kit folder, and did not work.